# Python: Histogram with log x-axis doesn't match histogram of log transformed values

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, probability-density

Below is a minimal example of something that puzzled me.

First we will create a random sample of values that follow a log normal distribution and the associated probability density function.  Then plot a histogram with a log x-axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mu, sigma = 0.5, 0.25 # mean and standard deviation
s = np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 10000)
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 100, density=True, align='mid')
x = np.linspace(min(bins), max(bins), 10000)
pdf = (np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))
        / (x * sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))
plt.plot(x, pdf, linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

[image: log-normal random sample of values]

Now we will log the values of the distribution and plot the without a log x-axis

```
plt.hist(np.log(s), 100, density=True, align='mid')
plt.plot(np.log(x), pdf, linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

[image: linear axis but logged values]

So my question is why does the pdf match the histogram bin values when I use a log axis but not when I log the values and then plot the histogram?

Answer (score 1):

you need to correct for your log transform, to fix this I'd just change the code to plot the PDF to:

```
plt.plot(np.log(x), pdf * x, linewidth=2)
```

the intuition behind this is that log transforming the data will cause the bins to get "wider" as x increases.  specifically, you need to look at the derivative of your transform

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I thought it must be something simple I was missing.  This makes complete sense.